# How to edit a message sent by a telegram-bot in Python

Tags: python, botframework, telegram-bot

I am using Python with Telegram bot API (20) and trying to edit a message my bot sent with the following code

```
msg = await context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id = update.effective_chat.id,
        text = "message",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, input_field_placeholder="Play!"
        ),
    )

await context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="edited text", message_id=msg.id)
```

I am getting the following error

> raise BadRequest(message) telegram.error.BadRequest: Message can't be
> edited

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TelegramBots/comments/6vxemq/badrequest_message_cant_be_edited/) Explaining that it might be an attempt to edit the user's message which is not editable by the bot, I made sure I am editing the message the bot sent, and that it's the right ID

I also read it might be an issue of the message not finishing to update, I used `await` and tried using `asyncio.sleep(5)` before the edit attempt with no success and the same error.

How can I edit the message the bot sent?

Comment: The issue in your code is related to `reply_markup`, without this your code is working fine, what eaxctly are you trying to do?

Comment: From [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) `editMessageText` method "Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards."

Comment: I am working on a trivia game, the markup I am sending is for creating a keyboard with the possible answers, and the edit is for displaying a timer of how long you have left to answer. So the problem is that the msg with markup cannot be edited?

Comment: yeah, It's mentioned in the docs, try using linline keyboard with callback